# htaccess redirect from folderA to subfolder in folderB

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdirectory

how could I redirect to the child folder?

there is a folderA:               "aaa.com/folderA/"
need to redirect to targetFolder :"aaa.com/folderB/targetFolder"

Thanks a lot

Comment: What have you tried? What went wrong? (by the way, I believe you're looking for the RedirectMatch directive. [Here](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/301-redirect-with-mod_rewrite-or-redirectmatch.html) are some random examples, these should get you started)

Answer (score 0):

Put this code @ the htaccess in the main directory (aaa) :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^folderA/(.*)$  /folderB/targetFolder/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```